# What are the pitfalls in BELLATRIX test framework?

Tags: automated-tests

I recently started studying [bellatrix framework](https://bellatrix.solutions/), [link to github](https://github.com/AutomateThePlanet/BELLATRIX)

I can't find a place where it is compared to other test frameworks.

What are the pitfalls in BELLATRIX test framework(c# language)?